# List all classes that extends a specifc class

Tags: php, zend-framework

In a Zend Framework project, I want to get a list of all classes that extends a specific class. Problem is, that these classes are not in the list of `get_declared_classes()` because they are not loaded so far.

It should work like a plugin list, and all "public viewable" classes extend a specific class, so I can "filter" them.

Comment: Just a sidenote: A class should never need to know anything about it's subclasses. If this is required, you did something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If these classes are not loaded, PHP does not know about them. So you have to load all the classes first, or parse classes' source codes, note which class `extends` what and then build your dependency tree

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seems, that I did not had a good idea ;)
I'd change the system to get all the plugins from a db, so it does not need the class-informations anymore.
Thanks for your answers and for guiding me on the right way ;-)